# Using WinSCP to reach web share

Tags: winscp, sharing

Our client has offered us a web share page, updated daily. You enter the url, say https://www.companyname.com/fldr, the page shows a popup for you to login w username and password, you get a page with download links on it and you click on them. Is there a way to access this via WinSCP, so that we could script a job to do it automatically? I opened WinSCP and tried to get to the page, but maybe got the port number wrong or such. Or maybe this can't be done? If not WinSCP, is there another way to do it easily? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No. HTTP/HTTPS is not on the [supported list of protocols for WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/protocols). If the remote server's admin could install WebDAV (which *is* supported by WinSCP) and offer the directory as a share via that protocol, then you could use WinSCP.

If that's not possible, another option is a "scriptable" HTTP download tool like [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/), or a website crawler/downloader/cloner like [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/).

Comment: +1 - Though it's not that HTTP is not supported. It's rather that HTTP alone cannot be used to manage a website.